# How can I index a subset of grouped data in dplyr based on values from another column?

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

Suppose I have a data.frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 10),
                   value = c(0, 0, 11, 5, 9, 8, 0, 6, 0, 9, 
                             4, 0, 0, 0, 18, 1, 1, 0, 3, 6), 
                   index = c(0, 4, 3, 3, 2, 6, 0, 1, 0, 5, 
                             3, 0, 6, 0, 2, 4, 5, 0, 2, 1))
```

Using dplyr, I would like to add a new column based on each group, that extracts the n-th value of the reversed sorted non-zero values of the column "value", using the non-zero values in the column "index" as index n.

My desired output looks like this:

```
   group value index column_wanted
1      A      0     0             0
2      A      0     4             8
3      A     11     3             9
4      A      5     3             9
5      A      9     2             9
6      A      8     6             5
7      A      0     0             0
8      A      6     1            11
9      A      0     0             0
10     A      9     5             6
11     B      4     3             4
12     B      0     0             0
13     B      0     6             1
14     B      0     0             0
15     B     18     2             6
16     B      1     4             3
17     B      1     5             1
18     B      0     0             0
19     B      3     2             6
20     B      6     1            18
```

The task can be achieved by first creating a subset of df containing just non-zero values and then creating the new column as follows:

```
df_no0 <- df %>% filter(index != 0)

df_no0 <- df_no0 %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(correct_col = rev(sort(value))[index])

df_no0

# A tibble: 14 × 4
# Groups:   group [2]
   group value index correct_col
   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 A          0     4           8
 2 A         11     3           9
 3 A          5     3           9
 4 A          9     2           9
 5 A          8     6           5
 6 A          6     1          11
 7 A          9     5           6
 8 B          4     3           4
 9 B          0     6           1
10 B         18     2           6
11 B          1     4           3
12 B          1     5           1
13 B          3     2           6
14 B          6     1          18
```

We can then `rbind` this to a subset of df containing just the zero values:

```
df_just0 <- df %>% filter(index == 0)

df_final <- df_no0 %>% 
  rbind(df_just0 %>% mutate(correct_col = 0))
  arrange(group)

df_final

# A tibble: 20 × 4
# Groups:   group [2]
   group value index correct_col
   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 A          0     4           8
 2 A         11     3           9
 3 A          5     3           9
 4 A          9     2           9
 5 A          8     6           5
 6 A          6     1          11
 7 A          9     5           6
 8 A          0     0           0
 9 A          0     0           0
10 A          0     0           0
11 B          4     3           4
12 B          0     6           1
13 B         18     2           6
14 B          1     4           3
15 B          1     5           1
16 B          3     2           6
17 B          6     1          18
18 B          0     0           0
19 B          0     0           0
20 B          0     0           0
```

which gives me the desired output (the row order does not matter).

This works, but I am looking for a "cleaner" and shorter solution that avoids "cutting" the data.frame into several parts and rbinding them in the end (the real data has hundreds of groups and several thousands of observations).

So I tried something like this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(wrong_column = ifelse(index == 0, 0, 
            rev(sort(value[value != 0]))[index[index != 0]]))

# A tibble: 20 × 4
# Groups:   group [2]
   group value index wrong_column
   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 A          0     0            0
 2 A          0     4            9
 3 A         11     3            9
 4 A          5     3            9
 5 A          9     2            5
 6 A          8     6           11
 7 A          0     0            0
 8 A          6     1            8
 9 A          0     0            0
10 A          9     5            9
11 B          4     3            4
12 B          0     0            0
13 B          0     6            6
14 B          0     0            0
15 B         18     2            1
16 B          1     4            6
17 B          1     5           18
18 B          0     0            0
19 B          3     2            1
20 B          6     1            6
```

I don't really understand what is going on here, but this does not give me what I want.
I also tried the `case_when` function, but I am not able to work with it well as it keeps throwing an error that the LHS and the RHS do not match.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

(I am using R 4.3.2. and dplyr version 1.1.2)

Comment: Welcome to SO! this is a great first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `replace` to only fill the vector of non-0 values.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(column_wanted = replace(index, index != 0, rev(sort(value[value != 0]))[index[index != 0]]))

#    group value index column_wanted
# 1      A     0     0             0
# 2      A     0     4             8
# 3      A    11     3             9
# 4      A     5     3             9
# 5      A     9     2             9
# 6      A     8     6             5
# 7      A     0     0             0
# 8      A     6     1            11
# 9      A     0     0             0
# 10     A     9     5             6
# 11     B     4     3             4
# 12     B     0     0             0
# 13     B     0     6             1
# 14     B     0     0             0
# 15     B    18     2             6
# 16     B     1     4             3
# 17     B     1     5             1
# 18     B     0     0             0
# 19     B     3     2             6
# 20     B     6     1            18
```

---

**Explanation**

`ifelse` is slightly different than `replace` because it uses the original vector size (`index`) and not the new one (`index[index != 0]`). It then recycles if the size is too short.

If you check values for the first group:

```r
with(df[df$group == "A",], rev(sort(value[value != 0]))[index[index != 0]], 0)
#[1]  8  9  9  9  5 11  6
```

What `ifelse` does is to create a vector of size `index`, with 0s when index is 0, and the values above if not, but it does not *`replace`* the values.

```r
# sorted values to match group size (recycled)
#[1]  8  9  9  9  5 11  6  8  9  9

# with 0s (output of ifelse)
#[1]  0  9  9  9  5 11  0  8  0  9

# correct output (replace)
#[1]  0  8  9  9  9  5  0 11  0  6
```

Comment: Wow, I have never used `replace` for purposes like this, thank you! Unfortunately, I get an error when I use your solution on my real data: 
`Error in mutate():
! Can't supply .by when .data is a grouped data frame.`
I need to group the data (based on several columns) to do some other operations on the data.frame, how can I keep these groups?

Comment: Use `group_by` instead. See edit. This is a matter of `dplyr` updates

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I realized I can just delete the `.by = group` and stick to `group_by()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach you can use:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[index!=0, t:=sort(value[value>0],T)[index], group][, t:=nafill(t,fill=0)]
```

Output:

```
     group value index     t
    <char> <num> <num> <num>
 1:      A     0     0     0
 2:      A     0     4     8
 3:      A    11     3     9
 4:      A     5     3     9
 5:      A     9     2     9
 6:      A     8     6     5
 7:      A     0     0     0
 8:      A     6     1    11
 9:      A     0     0     0
10:      A     9     5     6
11:      B     4     3     4
12:      B     0     0     0
13:      B     0     6     1
14:      B     0     0     0
15:      B    18     2     6
16:      B     1     4     3
17:      B     1     5     1
18:      B     0     0     0
19:      B     3     2     6
20:      B     6     1    18
```